# OnPost Execute method how can I pass image from one Fragment to other activity. Able to pass the image from drawable folder using Bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments

OnPost Execute method how can I pass image from one Fragment to other activity. Able to pass the image from drawable folder using Bundle. Loding product details from server and able to other information except Image to other Activity.

```
 package sanjay.apackage.torcente.com.torcentemotors;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
//private TextView tvData;
private ListView lvMovies;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    //Image loader
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
      .cacheInMemory(true)
      .cacheOnDisk(true)
      .build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getContext())       //getApplicationContext()

            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)

            .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); // Do it on Application start

    lvMovies = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvMovies);
    new JSONTask().execute("http://torcentemotors.com/app_001/productsInfoNew.php");





    return view;
}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<MovieModel> > {

    @Override
    protected List<MovieModel> doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line  = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }


            //return buffer.toString();
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject  = new JSONObject(finalJson);

            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("movies");



            List<MovieModel> movieModelList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i< parentArray.length() ;i++ ) {

                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                MovieModel movieModel = new MovieModel();

                movieModel.setProduct_name(finalObject.getString("product_name"));

                movieModel.setProduct_price(finalObject.getInt("product_price"));
                movieModel.setProduct_image(finalObject.getString("product_image"));
                movieModel.setProduct_color(finalObject.getString("product_color"));
                movieModel.setCover_image(finalObject.getString("cover_image"));
                movieModel.setOriginal_price(finalObject.getInt("original_price"));
                movieModel.setApp_desc(finalObject.getString("app_desc"));



                //adding the final object to the list
                movieModelList.add(movieModel);


            }

            //return finalBufferedData.toString();
            return movieModelList;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if( connection != null){
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if(reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        final MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.rownew, result );
        ////  getApplicationContext()   // getActivity is added by me
        lvMovies.setAdapter(adapter);



        //set data to list
        lvMovies.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              //  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position)+" is selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                MovieModel movieModel = (MovieModel) adapter.getItem(position);




                Intent intent = new Intent("sanjay.apackage.torcente.com.torcentemotors.product_details");
                //intent.putExtra("product_image", movieModel.getProduct_image());
                //sanjay //
                intent.putExtra("id",position);

                intent.putExtra("product_name",movieModel.getProduct_name());
                intent.putExtra("product_price", movieModel.getProduct_price());
                intent.putExtra("product_color", movieModel.getProduct_color());
                intent.putExtra("original_price", movieModel.getOriginal_price());
                intent.putExtra("app_desc", movieModel.getApp_desc());

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();


                bundle.putInt("image",R.drawable.ban);

                bundle.putInt("image2",R.drawable.fz25);

                intent.putExtras(bundle);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }

}


public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    private List<MovieModel> movieModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater ;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        movieModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource ;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   // context is added by me.



    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        viewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null ) {

            holder = new viewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);

            holder.tvIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvIcon);
            holder.tvcover  = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvcover);

            holder.tvproduct_name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById((R.id.tvproduct_name));

            holder.tvproduct_price = (TextView)convertView.findViewById((R.id.tvproduct_price));
            holder.tvproduct_color = (TextView)convertView.findViewById((R.id.tvproduct_color));
            holder.tvoriginal_price = (TextView)convertView.findViewById((R.id.tvoriginal_price));
            holder.tvapp_desc = (TextView)convertView.findViewById((R.id.tvapp_desc));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else{
            holder = (viewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }


        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(movieModelList.get(position).getProduct_image(), holder.tvIcon);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(movieModelList.get(position).getCover_image(), holder.tvcover);
        //holder.tvproduct_id.setText(" Product ID : " +movieModelList.get( position ).getProduct_id());
        //holder.tvcategory_id.setText("Category ID : " +movieModelList.get(position).getCategory_id());
        //holder.tvsub_category_id.setText("Sub Category ID : " +movieModelList.get(position).getSub_category_id());
        holder.tvproduct_name.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getProduct_name());
        //holder.tvproduct_code.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getProduct_code());
        holder.tvproduct_price.setText("BookingPrice : "+movieModelList.get(position).getProduct_price());
        holder.tvproduct_color.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getProduct_color());
        holder.tvoriginal_price.setText("Price : "+movieModelList.get(position).getOriginal_price());
        //holder.tvapp_desc.setText(movieModelList.get(position).getApp_desc());

        return convertView;

    }

    class viewHolder{

        private ImageView tvIcon ;
        private ImageView tvcover ;
        private TextView  tvproduct_id;
        private TextView  tvcategory_id;
        private TextView  tvsub_category_id;
        private TextView  tvproduct_name;
        private TextView  tvproduct_code;
        private TextView  tvproduct_color;
        private TextView  tvproduct_price; 
        private TextView  tvoriginal_price;
        private TextView  tvapp_desc;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: you can pass image url to other activity and on that activity you can load image using any library like Picasso.

Comment: What's your image source? Url or a resource in drawable folder?

Comment: Image Url  - http:\\torcentemotors.com\images_products\Fascino0Fascino.jpg

Comment: Then Ragini's comment is your answer. :)

Comment: I got the Image URL on next Activity, How to load Image using Picasso.

Comment: Thanks Bro, Its working Now.